# JQuery .attr();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML for consideration...

```
<ul class="foo">
    <li class="bar"><a>Here #1</a></li>
    <li class="bar"><a href="#2">Here #2</a></li>
    <li class="bar"><a href="#3">Here #3</a></li>
    <li class="bar"><a href="#4">Here #4</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that I have an anchor tag that does not have an href in the first list item tag. I want to use JQuery to add the href to the tag. I tried doing it like this (it did not work):

```
var fooBar;

fooBar = $('li.bar').children().first();
fooBar.attr('a', 'href="#1"');
```

I thought maybe I needed to pass in the index, but I figured the .first() would grab the correct element. Either way my code fails to do what I want.

I would greatly appreciate any direction and/or input.

Comment: **[.attr() Doc Link](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Comment: Really??? That is not an answer that is an obvious resource that I already used as you can see by the syntax. Shameless way to get in a response.

Comment: I was just directing you to the correct syntax instead of giving you the answer so that you would learn. Nothing else. If you would have specified the resources you used I wouldnt have commented. :)

Comment: Tous-chez! Please forgive my gaff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is this line

```
fooBar.attr('a', 'href="#1");
```

Do it as bellow

```
fooBar.attr('href', '#1');
```

Comment: I upvoted all of the answers since they all worked. However, you pointing out where my mistake was and how I can learn from it was the best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct way of setting attribute value:

```
fooBar.attr('href', "#1");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
$('li.bar').children('a').first().attr('href', '#1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var add_attr = $('.foo > li:first-child');

$(add_attr).find("a").attr('href','#');
```